# Cloudformation not update TaskDefinition revision

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I have Cloudformation template with TaskDefinition section.
After deploying the stack to AWS, a TaskDefinition with revision 1 is created.

I want update TaskDefinition in Cloudformation template (add or remove ContainerDefinition), but after updating the stack, a TaskDefinition is not updated (still revision 1).

I try to use "Family" element in TaskDefinition, but new revision is not created.

Please, can anybody help me? What i am doing wrong?

Comment: That's default behavior for cloudformation. It replaces the task definition rather than creating a new revision. Setting "Family" should be the correct fix. Not enough information here to debug further.

Comment: Thanks for reply, replace will be ok, but when i update stack with new template, where some changes was made in configuration of TaskDefinition, nothing will be changed in taskdefinition after success stack update. for example, i have following test Cloudformation template: https://pastebin.com/aX9kKNEL, after stack create TaskDefinition will be created successfully. when i change something in taskdefinition (e.q. name, port mapping) and update stack, no change will be made in taskdefinition. (still same name and revision with older config)

Comment: How did you update your task definition, when i update my stack it deregisters the current task definition and makes it inactive. There is only one task definition which is active at any time when i use CFT.

I have a family section it still deregisters and keeps only one active TD